# How to deal with BrowserSync and gulp-watch?

Tags: sass, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

I trying to setting up my gulpfile.js file with features like "scss to css transformation" / watcher / live reload.

```
// Variables
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var source = './src';
var destination = './dist';
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

// Server
gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'src'
        }
    })
});

// Task build : Scss -> Css
gulp.task('buildCss', function () {
    return gulp.src(source + '/assets/styles/*.scss')
        .pipe(plugins.sass())
        .pipe(plugins.cssbeautify({indent: '  '}))
        .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/assets/styles/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(source + '/assets/styles/*.scss', gulp.series('buildCss'));
});

gulp.task('startDev', gulp.series('browserSync', 'watch'));
```

First, I built the css transformation code, after I did the watcher and it was working well but when I added "browserSync" part, it breaks all.
When I launch "startDev", new tab open so the server is launching i guess, but nothing happen after as you can see on the console here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/u82Jn.png

Do you have any idea where the problem can come from ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First step: don't name your task and the package required both `browserSync`.  Change one of them.

Comment: I renamed my task "sync". But it lead to the same result on the console :/

Comment: You have this option: `baseDir: 'src'` but your css destination is `dist`.  So you are trying to load `src` html - should that be `dist`?

Comment: Oh ok.. I replaced baseDir: 'src' by baseDir: destination which is equal to ./dist. Nothing changed yet :/

Comment: For everyone who want to do nearly the same thing : I find the solution in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgMQeLymAdU